# Trying to reference a variable in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm currently working on a music player project. Each song has an individual song row with a play/pause icon(that can play/pause the song), song name, etc. On the bottom of the player is a player play/pause bar that can control the song as well.

My issue is that when I play a song through the bottom player bar icon will switch appropriately, but the song row icon will not.

I have a JavaScript function that dynamically creates a song row.

```
var createSongRow = function(songNumber, songName, songLength) {
    var template =
    '<tr class="album-view-song-item">'
    + '   <td class="song-item-number" data-song-number="' + songNumber + '">' + songNumber + '</td>'
    + '   <td class="song-item-title">' + songName + '</td>'
    + '   <td class="song-item-duration">' + filterTimeCode(songLength) + '</td>'
   + '</tr>';

    var $row = $(template);
}
```

Within this same function I created a clickhandler function that sets the currently playing song and updates the player row icon.

```
var clickHandler = function () {

  var songNumber = parseInt($(this).attr('data-song-number'));

  if (currentlyPlayingSongNumber !== null) {
      // Revert to song number for currently playing song because user started playing next song.
      var currentlyPlayingCell = getSongNumberCell(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);
      currentlyPlayingCell.html(currentlyPlayingSongNumber);
  }
  if (currentlyPlayingSongNumber !== songNumber) {
      // Switch from Play -> Pause button to indicate new song is playing.
      $(this).html(pauseButtonTemplate);
      setSong(songNumber);
      currentSoundFile.play();
      updateSeekBarWhileSongPlays();
      var $volumeFill = $('.volume .fill');
      var $volumeThumb = $('.volume .thumb');
      $volumeFill.width(currentVolume + '%');
      $volumeThumb.css({left: currentVolume + '%'});
      updatePlayerBarSong();
  } else if (currentlyPlayingSongNumber === songNumber) {
      // Switch from Pause -> Play button to pause currently playing song.
        if (currentSoundFile.isPaused()) {
            $(this).html(pauseButtonTemplate);
            $('.main-controls .play-pause').html(playerBarPauseButton);
            currentSoundFile.play();
            updateSeekBarWhileSongPlays();
        } else {
            $(this).html(playButtonTemplate);
            $('.main-controls .play-pause').html(playerBarPlayButton);
            currentSoundFile.pause();
        }
    }
};
```

This is where I'm having issues. The `$(this)` in the code above is referencing the class which I want to target in the function below. In the code below I've commented where I think the reference should occur.

```
var togglePlayFromPlayerBar = function() {

    if (currentSoundFile === null) {
        setSong(1);
        updatePlayerBarSong();
        updateSeekBarWhileSongPlays();
        $('.main-controls .play-pause').html(playerBarPauseButton);
        currentSoundFile.play();
        $('.song-item-number').first().html(pauseButtonTemplate);
        $(".volume > .seek-bar > .fill").css("width", "80.0%");
        $(".volume > .seek-bar > .thumb").css("left", "80.0%");
    } else if (currentSoundFile.isPaused()) {
        $('.main-controls .play-pause').html(playerBarPauseButton);
        currentSoundFile.play();
        //change player row icon;
    } else if (currentSoundFile != null) {
        $('.main-controls .play-pause').html(playerBarPlayButton);
        currentSoundFile.pause();
        //change player row icon;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you reduce your sample to point problem better ? just make simple sample code, I can't understand in 2nd sample where you commented about reference,